# OSG shared vertex array duplicated

Tags: qt, openscenegraph

I'm using openscenegraph to render a scene with ~9000 vertices. Each Drawable is a line (I must keep it as it represent a "bar"). So I use the function `setVertexArray()` with the same vertex array on each `Geometry` node but use a different `DrawElementsUInt`.

With a total of 12000 drawable, I should have 9000 vertices, but I have around 200 000 000 vertices and twice the drawables. (I see that using the "S" key in the viewer).

I there something I could do to force the drawable to use the same Array and not to copy it ?

I'm using OSG in Qt.

m_vertices is a osg::vec3Array* wich contains 9000 values
addBar is called 12000 times.

```
void addBar(osg::Node *geode)
{
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Geometry> bar = new osg::Geometry;
    bar.get()->setVertexArray(m_vertices);
    bar->setUseDisplayList(false);
    osg::DrawElementsUInt *ids = new osg::DrawElementsUInt(osg::PrimitiveSet::LINES);
    ids->push_back(/* first Id*/);
    ids->push_back(/* second id */);
    bar.get()->addPrimitiveSet(ids);   
    geode->asGeode()->addDrawable(bar.get());
}
```

Comment: is that better ? I cant show real code as Its not my property.

Comment: ok, I figured out that using `osgFX::Outline` as group node was doubling vertex number. But I still have `number of geometry nodes * number of vertices`

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be using VBOs, so OSG is making a per node copy of the `m_vertices` array and uploading it ot the GPU.

So remove the line:

```
bar->setUseDisplayList(false);
```

And replace it with:

```
bar->setUseVertexBufferObjects(true);
```

**UPDATE:**

Upon further reflection, this is not enough.  Under the hood OSG is simply creating a seperate VBO for each Geode - not what we want.  So the solution (according to this post on the [OSG forums](http://forum.openscenegraph.org/viewtopic.php?t=10443&view=previous)) is create an `osg::VertexBufferObject` and fill it with your vertices, then add it to an `osg::Vec3Array` (your `m_vertices`) using `setVertexBufferObject(..)`.

Comment: I just tried it and I still have the same amount of vertex :(

Comment: is the problem coming from my scenegraph which has many geometry nodes with all the same vertex array ?

Comment: @Brugere That's what it looks like.  You should have a single VBO that all the geometry nodes use as their vertex source but with different primitive set for each defining the offset.  Which I would have thought is what the above does.

Comment: seen it, i'm trying it now

Comment: doesnt work too. Im merging all geometry in one to avoid the problem.... OSG really SUCK, openGL would have do it easily